# How use the original sources when debugging Nativescript+Webpack

Tags: webpack, nativescript

Im trying to debug a simple test app that throws an exception in the first lines in the `app.js` file, however, the stack traces point to the `bundle.js` file. That is not useful. How do I see the original code in the stack traces?

I'm using NS 5.4.2 and nativescript-dev-webpack@0-24-1.

Comment: Did you enable sourceMap (`--env.sourceMap`)?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't help. According to [this comment](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-webpack/issues/603#issuecomment-466973774) it shouldn't matter anyway. Setting the `--no-bundle` flag seems to help but that's not the point

Comment: This is already fixed in NativeScript 6.0.0, I suggest you wait for the release candidate and the blog post a few more days.